# Changing Google Analytics link from one BigQuery project to another

Tags: google-analytics, google-bigquery, integration

I have a BigQuery project (project1) that has been integrated with a Google Analytics Premium account. I have edit access to the GA account but do not have access to project1 -- it's a long story, but in a nutshell no one has owner privileges and only a handful of people have edit access. I'd like to move the GA pipe from project1 to another table in a different BigQuery project (project2), of which I am the owner. I followed this [link](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3416092) (step 3), and the only option I could find is to unlink the old BQ project. However, I'm a little hesitant to do this because I'm not 100%  sure that I'll have the option to redirect the GA data to the new BQ project (project2). Does anyone know if I'll have this option once I click "unlink" ?

Comment: As you have Google Analytics Premium, that includes access to dedicated support specialists. This seems like a question for them.

Comment: As @FelipeHoffa mentioned, you should consult with GA support, but from what I think I know, if you unlink Property "A" from BQ Project "Z", you will lose the ability to backfill the data but only if you try to link it back to BQ "Z". However, if you unlink GA "A" from BQ "Z", and you instead link it BQ "Y", then it should be fine. Best to double check.

Comment: Thanks. I will contact the support specialists before doing anything I regret.